# Calculating Reorder Point with Negative Binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm an intern working on a project that requires calculating minimum stock levels for skus with low demand and high volatility. I found from research that a negative binomial distribution is best suited for accounting for the high number of zero values in my demand data. I'm unclear of the process of determining the R-value for the reorder calculation and the formula you would use to get the reorder quantity. I do not have a background in statistics and only understand how to calculate reorder point with demand that's normally distributed. I have 52 weeks of demand data. Is there a reorder point formula for negative binomial distributions? What is the process of determining the parameters of my negative binomial distribution "R" at a certain service level "95%")? Is there a way to do it in excel?